# Terraform & GCP : Cannot add Owner in a group, can only add members

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to create a group that will list all the people allowed in my organization by using the following blocks :

```
resource "google_cloud_identity_group" "all-org-users-to-whitelist" {
  display_name         = "all-org-users-to-whitelist"
  description          = "A group that onboards a user on the organization, and enables org level policies such as IP restriction of connection to the console."
  initial_group_config = "WITH_INITIAL_OWNER"
  group_key {
    id = "all-org-users-to-whitelist@domain.fr"
  }
  parent = "customers/${data.google_organization.org.directory_customer_id}"
  labels = {
    "cloudidentity.googleapis.com/groups.discussion_forum" = "" # Required by doc
  }
}

resource "google_cloud_identity_group_membership" "all-org-users" {
  group    = google_cloud_identity_group.all-org-users-to-whitelist.id
  for_each = {
    for user in var.all_org_users :
    user.email_id => user.role
  }

  preferred_member_key {
    id = each.key
  }
  roles {
    name = each.value
  }
}
```

Input example :

```
all_org_users = [
  {
    role     = "MEMBER"
    email_id = "user1@domain.fr"
  },
  {
    role     = "MEMBER"
    email_id = "user2@domain.fr"
  },
]
```

This adds these users into the group as members. The problem arrises when I try adding a user as **Owner**...

```
  {
    role     = "OWNER"
    email_id = "user3@domain.fr"
  },
```

I get the following error :

```
│ Error: Error creating GroupMembership: googleapi: Error 400: MEMBER role must be specified
│ Details:
│ [
│   {
│     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
│     "fieldViolations": [
│       {
│         "description": "MEMBER role must be specified",
│         "field": "resource.roles"
│       }
│     ]
│   }
│ ]
│
│   with google_cloud_identity_group_membership.all-org-users["user3@domain.fr"],
│   on groups_x_users.tf line 15, in resource "google_cloud_identity_group_membership" "all-org-users":
│   15: resource "google_cloud_identity_group_membership" "all-org-users" {
│
```

Mind you, I can do this on the console with a super-user account... What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Okay... So there was a bit of an issue in the syntax, although I don't know why it is this way.

In order to add an **Owner** the `google_cloud_identity_group_membership` needs to be set up this way :

```
resource "google_cloud_identity_group_membership" "all-org-owners" {
  group    = google_cloud_identity_group.all-org-users-to-whitelist.id
  for_each = toset(var.all_org_owners)


  preferred_member_key {
    id = each.value
  }
  roles {
    name = "MEMBER"
  }
  roles {
    name = "OWNER"
  }
}
```

With the `roles` parameter set to `MEMBER` AND `OWNER`